# How to limit decimal points in Matlab output?

Tags: matlab, decimal

My main code is a tcl code but it calls a Matlab algorithm for calculations. The calculation results are then fed to the main tcl code. I want to limit the decimal points in output to 2. Currently, I'm getting 680.9166666666666. I would like it to be 680.92. Is there any Matlab command I can use for this?

Comment: what about `format short g` ?

Comment: What is your output type? Are you writing to a file? Command window? I would recommend looking at [`fprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) or [`sprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), depending on  your needs. See the [`formatSpec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) argument for more information on field widths.

Comment: From what I understand, format shortg will change only the way outputs are displayed in Matlab command window. What I want is to actually round off the outputs to lesser decimal points before feeding them back to the tcl script.

Comment: Then I think @excaza is right on spot

Comment: @KritiKapoor What are you looking to gain by feeding in a number to two decimal points? Unless you change the [data type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html) you're not going to change how the number is stored in memory. Both `fprintf()` and `sprintf()` output a string, which you'd have to convert back into a number with your second function.

Comment: Output type is double. This outputs feeds to a tcl file which later generates tables where the output is displayed. I want the output to have lesser digits to make the table clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you have either [`sprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) or [`fprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). The main difference between the two is that `sprintf()` outputs a string to a variable and `fprintf()` outputs to a file or to the command window.

For example:

```
a = 123.456;

% Method 1
a2 = sprintf('%.2f', a);

% Method 2
fprintf('%.2f\n', a)

% Method 3
fID = fopen('testfile.txt', 'w+'); % Open file for writing, discard existing contents
fprintf(fID, '%.2f\n', a);
fclose(fID);
```

See the documentation on the [`formatSpec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) argument for information on how to specify the format you need.

---

As an extension of my comments above, this manipulation is probably better done in your Tcl script prior to outputting to the table. I'm not familiar with the language but I'm assuming it utilizes something similar to `sprintf()`, which is a pretty generic programming command.